# What are free and bound variables in mathematics?

Tags: integration, limits, functions

Especially in function definitions. How to treat the x in f(x) for example? Like a placeholder or something else? Can someone explain these concepts well?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables